# Realtime Notifications from Laravel API project to separate Laravel Web project

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-7, real-time-updates

Basically, i have a project which is distinguished between 2 Laravel folders. API (Talking to DB) and Web
We are calling APIs on Web end to achieve results.
So according to new requirements, we need to add realtime notifications to be sent to Web end.
I don't have an idea how to achieve this?

If i talk about tutorials or content available on internet, they mostly using only one Laravel folder for their logic (Backend) and Website. So its really tough for me to how to send realtime notifications from API to Web?